# Multiple blob creation for creating multiple PDFs

Tags: class, list, pagereference, blob, array

I have below piece of code to generate a PDF file. I have a requirement to create multiple blobs for multiple PDFs. I am trying to do so but not working as expected.

**Apex code**

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='+formquantity);
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);

// Take the PDF content
Blob b = pageRef.getContent();
```

// PageRef and Blob both needs to be array or list kind of.

Please find what I intend to achieve is something like this.

```
counter=1;
form = integer.valueof(formquantity);
while (counter>0 && form>0) {
    System.debug('counter@@'+counter);
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='+form);
    pageRef.setRedirect(false);
    blob b1 = pageRef.getContent();
    b.add(b1); //This line throws Null Pointer
    form-=5;
    counter++;
}
```

This code is fine to compile but throws Null pointer in add line ( **b.add(b1);**)

Comment: `pageRef.getContent();` instead try`pageRef.getContentAsPDF();`

Comment: @Ratan if page have render as PDF, then getContent would work also. SFDC_Learner -- It still not clear what are you trying to do. If you need multiple PDF, then do getContent in loop, but beware limits

Comment: I have placed what I am trying to achieve. Please have a look. I need a list of blobs for attaching multiple PDFs in email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your code to look next way:

```
List<Blob> pdf_data = new List<Blob>();

Integer form_number = Integer.valueOf(formquantity);
while (form_number > 0) {
    PageReference pafe_ref = 
        new PageReference(  '/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='
                          + form_number.toString());//Change form number every time
    pdf_data.add(pafe_ref.getContent());
    form_number -= 5;
}
```

Remarks:

- **counter** variable is not really used;
- List of Blob need to be created before in reference url
- form_number needs to be used to
  generate uniq pdf (not sure about it)

Comment: Please find my edit in question. Compile is fine but throws error of null pointer after first run in this line  b.add(b1);

Comment: @SFDC_Learner in your updated code you need to initialize list of Blob like:
`List<Blob> b = new List<Blob>();`

Comment: I have done that at very begining. Sorry forgot to mention. public List<Blob> b{get;set;}

Comment: @SFDC_Learner so, please refer to my answer or do b = new List<Blob>(); somewhere before loop

Comment: Thanks that declaration was having the issue. But now it causes issue as List out of bound exception here. for(integer i = 0; i <counter; i++)
{
   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
   efa.setBody(b[i]); // List out of bound
   lstFileAttachments.add(efa);
}

Comment: Please find the separate question here. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110423/list-out-of-bound-exception-at-listblob

Comment: Instead of for(integer i = 0; i <counter; i++) use for(integer i = 0; i <b.size(); i++)