# List out of bound exception at List<Blob>

Tags: apex, error, exception, blob, unexpectedexception

I have below piece of code where I get below error. Here b is the List of blobs.
**Error**

```
List index out of bounds: 3
```

**Apex Code**

```
for(integer i = 0; i <counter; i++)
{
   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
   efa.setBody(b[i]); // List index out of bounds: 3

   lstFileAttachments.add(efa);
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code. How does counter get its value?

Comment: Instead of for(integer i = 0; i <counter; i++) use for(integer i = 0; i <b.size(); i++) in refer to prev question

Comment: Superb. Yes incrementing i was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead `counter` use `b.size()`

```
for(integer i = 0; i <b.size(); i++)
{
   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
   efa.setBody(b[i]);

   lstFileAttachments.add(efa);
}
```

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Most welcome..